# How can generate a sequence number inside a LINQ select?

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting a hard time generating a sequence number for my list using Linq Select.

I tried to use a normal variable i then increment it inside but it's not working.

```
var grouped = (from x in jOMACDetails
                       group x by new { x.MAWorkCode, x.ConstructionNumber } into g
                       let f = g.First()
                       select new UtilityReceivingReportDetailEntity
                       {
                           DefaultAccountCode = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.AccountTitleCode) ? f.AccountTitleName.Trim() : f.AccountTitleCode.Trim(),
                           CompanyID = CurrentContext.CurrentCompanyID,
                           RRNumber = socnumber.Trim(),
                           RRSequenceNumber = (short)???, // <---- Here is the container the I need to be sequence
                           //...............
                       }).AsEnumerable();
```

can someone help me about this?
thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the code for the class _UtilityReceivingReportDetailEntity_ What is the datatype for RRSequenceNumber?

Comment: What kind of sequence? Any example will clear your question a bit.

Comment: simple sequence # @RahulSingh ,just 1, 2, 3, ..., n

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update integer property of all objects in a List with sequential number using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76766452/how-to-update-integer-property-of-all-objects-in-a-list-with-sequential-number-u)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534869(v=vs.100).aspx) overload which projects each element of a sequence into a new form by incorporating the element's index automatically:

```
var grouped = jOMACDetails.GroupBy(x => new { x.MAWorkCode, x.ConstructionNumber })
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .Select((r, index) => new UtilityReceivingReportDetailEntity
        {
           DefaultAccountCode = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.AccountTitleCode) ? r.AccountTitleName.Trim() : r.AccountTitleCode.Trim(),
           CompanyID = CurrentContext.CurrentCompanyID,
           RRNumber = socnumber.Trim(),
           RRSequenceNumber = index
        })
    .AsEnumerable();
```

Sadly, there is not any query expression which uses that overload. So, I wrote my answer in method syntax. But, you can use `.Select` after finishing your query expression if you wish. But, IMHO there is no need.

Answer (score 4):

You´re looking for this?

```
var i = 0;
var grouped = (from x in jOMACDetails
    group x by new { x.MAWorkCode, x.ConstructionNumber } into g
    let f = g.First()
    select new UtilityReceivingReportDetailEntity
    {
        DefaultAccountCode = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f.AccountTitleCode) ? f.AccountTitleName.Trim() : f.AccountTitleCode.Trim(),
        CompanyID = CurrentContext.CurrentCompanyID,
        RRNumber = socnumber.Trim(),
        RRSequenceNumber = i++
    }).AsEnumerable();
```