# How to update integer property of all objects in a List with sequential number using LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq

How to update `Id` property of all objects in the `List` with sequential number using Linq?

Expected result is `BookList` where all `BookDetail` have its `Id` of 1 to 3.

```
public class BookDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

List<BookDetail> BookList = new List<BookDetail>
{
    new BookDetail{Id = 0, Title = "Aaa"},
    new BookDetail{Id = 0, Title = "Bbb"},
    new BookDetail{Id = 0, Title = "Ccc"}
};
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] yoru question and write more detail about "If updating is not possible"? Do you expect BookDetail to be immutable?

Comment: Why do you have to do it in LINQ? Why not a `foreach` loop?

Comment: @rudolf_franek, I have deleted this part as I thought `Linq` is capable only to select and create a new collection, not update one.

Comment: "Linq is capable only to select and create a new collection, not update one" It's _designed_ only to select. it _can_ be used to update but in almost all cases it _shouldn't_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `All` to set the id on each item.

```
var id = 1;

BookList.All(item => { item.Id = id++; return true; });
```

`ForEach` is another option, but it is only available for `List`.
If you have an `Enumerable` and don't want/need to convert to a `List`, then this is the linq method available.

As for using a `for` or `foreach` loop, neither are linq and were excluded for that reason.

Comment: Classic example of using the wrong tool for the job. `All` will certainly iterate over all of the items, but that's not its purpose. It's purpose is to check if all of the items pass a test. Better to use `ForEach` or even (gasp) a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @HereticMonkey `ForEach` is not available for `Enumerable`, in this case its fine since its a `List`, but for other collection types this is how I approach the iteration.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Clear that classic `foreach` loop would be better performance-wise, but learning `Linq` at the moment.

Comment: If you're learning LINQ, learn to use functions for their intended purpose and not for side effects.

Comment: For what use cases `ForEach` will be better choice then `foreach` loop?

Comment: @Megrez7 use-case:  disallowed to start "tabs vs. spaces" flame war :)... Totally opinionated even for comments - but I'd say you'd be better off not using LINQ-like ForEach for modifying items.

Comment: LINQ shouldn't be used to modify items in the collection. Don't use LINQ for this. `BookList` is a `List<T>` and [`ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-7.0) is a method of `List<T>`. It is not part of LINQ and it is not an extension method. The code in this answer could be changed to `BookList.ForEach(book => book.Id = id++);` (That `ForEach` looks like LINQ is, in my opinion, irrelevant but the view of @AlexeiLevenkov is also reasonable. What matters more is to be consistent with the existing code and the team consensus.)

Answer (score 1):

Linq is for *querying*, not *updating*. You *could* use linq to project to a *new* list of new objects if you include the item index in the query:

```
var newBookList = BookList.Select(
    (b, i) => new BookDetail {
        Id = i,
        Title = b.Title
    }
).ToList()
```

But this not only creates a new *list*, it creates new *objects* within the list, effectively doubling the memory used.

If you instead want to *modify* the contents of the list, just use a `for` loop to easily get the index:

```
for(int i=0; i < BookList.Length; i++)
{
    BookList[i].Id = i;
}
```

`ForEach` *could* be used, but it does not support an index parameter, so you'd have to create your own variable and increment it within the `ForEach`. Plus, there is debate as to the usefulness of `ForEach` versus a traditional `foreach` loop (you'd have to create an index variable in a `foreach` also.

I appreciate you wanting to use this to "learn Linq", but part of learning how to use a tool is learning *when the tool should not be used*.